# Searching an entire workbook for keywords and then printing the results on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, search

I made a search page at the beginning of a work book. This page has a drop down that allows you to choose what category to search in, then you type your phrase or keyword into the search box and it finds all of the results. It then takes those results and pastes them in in the chart at the bottom of the search page. You then have the option to print out those results or clear the chart.  Pictures are also posted for better understanding.

[image: The Search Page] [image: Part of a Database Page]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    UpdateSearchBox
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Select Case TextBox1.Value
        Case "F"
            TextBox1.Value = "G"
        Case "E"
            TextBox1.Value = "F"
        Case "D"
            TextBox1.Value = "E"
        Case "C"
            TextBox1.Value = "D"
        Case "B"
            TextBox1.Value = "C"
        Case "A"
            TextBox1.Value = "B"
        Case "G"
            TextBox1.Value = "A"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    FindOne
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    UpdateSearchBox
End Sub

Sub UpdateSearchBox()
    Dim PageName As String, searchColumn As String, ListFiller As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        PageName = TextBox1.Value
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "A"
        Case "EQUIPMENT NAME"
            searchColumn = "C"
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "F"
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "G"
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "H"
        Case "PART NAME"
            searchColumn = "I"
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    lastRow = Sheets(PageName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        If lastRow <> 0 And PageName <> "" And searchColumn <> "" Then
        ListFiller = PageName & "!" & searchColumn & "2" & ":" & searchColumn & lastRow
        ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ListFiller
    End If
End Sub
Sub FindOne()

    Range("B19:J1500") = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim k As Integer, EndPasteLoopa As Integer
    Dim myText As String, searchColumn As String
    Dim totalValues As Long
    Dim nextCell As Range

    k = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    myText = ComboBox1.Value
    Set nextCell = Range("B20")
    If myText = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Address Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "A"
        Case "EQUIPMENT NAME"
            searchColumn = "C"
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "F"
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "G"
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "H"
        Case "PART NAME"
            searchColumn = "I"
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    For i = 2 To k
        totalValues = Sheets(i).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim AddressArray(totalValues) As String

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            AddressArray(j) = Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 1).Value
        Next j

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            If (myText = AddressArray(j)) Then
                EndPasteLoop = 1
                If (Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 2).Value = "") Then EndPasteLoop = Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 1).End(xlDown).Row - j - 1
                For r = 1 To EndPasteLoop
                    Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("A" & j + r, "I" & j + r).Value
                    Set nextCell = nextCell.Offset(1, 0)
                Next r
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Brief glance:`Range("A65536")` could be updated to `Cells(Rows.Count,"A")`. I'm not a fan of multi line delcarations, but glad you have each type explicit and avoided the variant trap. Welcome to CodeReview!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the changes I'd make

- Use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module

  - Eliminate all errors found by compiling the code (Debug -> CompileVBA Project)
  - (declare all variables, first of all)
- Remove the empty `Sub ComboBox1_Change()` declaration if you don't inded to use it
- Replace string comparisons such as `PageName <> ""` with

  - `PageName <> vbNullString` (faster)
  - `Len(PageName) > 0` (even faster)
- As pointed out in the comment, generalize the `lastRow` and `totalValues` statements

From:

> `lastRow = Sheets(PageName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

To

> ```
> With Sheets(PageName)
>     lastRow = .Range(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
> End With
> ```

---

To reduce total lines of code and make it a bit easier to maintain I'd replace the three Select statements with one separate Function, and use it like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = GetSelectedLetter(TextBox1.Value)
End Sub

Sub UpdateSearchBox()
    ...
    searchColumn = GetSelectedLetter(ComboBox2.Value)
    If InStr(searchColumn, "Please") > 0 Then MsgBox searchColumn
    ...
End Sub

Sub FindOne()
    ...
    searchColumn = GetSelectedLetter(ComboBox2.Value)
    If InStr(searchColumn, "Please") > 0 Then MsgBox searchColumn
    ...
End Sub


Public Function GetSelectedLetter(ByVal sel As String) As String
    Select Case sel
        Case "G", "EQUIPMENT NUMBER":   GetSelectedLetter = "A":    Exit Function
        Case "B", "EQUIPMENT NAME":     GetSelectedLetter = "C":    Exit Function
        Case "E", "DUPONT NUMBER":      GetSelectedLetter = "F":    Exit Function
        Case "F", "SAP NUMBER":         GetSelectedLetter = "G":    Exit Function
        Case "D":                       GetSelectedLetter = "E":    Exit Function
        Case "SSI NUMBER":              GetSelectedLetter = "H":    Exit Function
        Case "PART NAME":               GetSelectedLetter = "I":    Exit Function
        Case "C":                       GetSelectedLetter = "D":    Exit Function
        Case "A":                       GetSelectedLetter = "B":    Exit Function
        Case vbNullString:
            GetSelectedLetter = "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select
End Function
```

(not the standard indentation, but I find it visually easier to work with)

---

**Performance**

One improvement: start the search after moving all data to arrays (array of arrays specifically)

Example:

```
Public Sub SearchAllSheetsArrayOfArrays()
    Const SRC_VAL = "Test"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, tc As Long, tw As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lbr As Long, ubr As Long, lbc As Long, ubc As Long

    i = 1
    tw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ReDim arr(i To i + tw - 1)  'Place all data from each sheet in Variant sub-arrays

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            arr(j + 1) = ws.UsedRange
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    tw = j
    ReDim Preserve arr(i To tw) 'Trim the main Array if there are empty sheets

    For i = 1 To tw     'tw = total worksheets
        lbr = LBound(arr(i), 1): ubr = UBound(arr(i), 1)    'dimension 1 (rows)
        lbc = LBound(arr(i), 2): ubc = UBound(arr(i), 2)    'dimension 2 (cols)
        For r = lbr To ubr
            For c = lbc To ubc
                If Len(arr(i)(r, c)) > 0 Then
                    If InStr(arr(i)(r, c), SRC_VAL) > 0 Then tc = tc + 1 'collect vals
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    Debug.Print tc
End Sub
```

---

Ps. I used very short variable names to make the code fit in its window without scroll bars, but more descriptive names should be used - like in your posted code, but try to keep naming conventions consistent: all variables start with lower case letters, all procedures start with upper case letters

Comment: While the use of `:` is certainly more visually pleasing I would strongly caution anyone from using it. It is a known problem-causer and rarely does it result in a net improvement. Case in point, you have a bunch of `Exit Function`'s that aren't needed since the code would exit the function immediately after that command as is, and further your Function is called `GetSelectedLetter` but you are returning values to `GetSelection` (which isnt a declared variable). It may be pretty to look at, but indentation conventions are there for a reason :).

Comment: Also, I highly recommend avoidance of `Dim a as Foo, b as Baz, c as Baz...` since this pattern causes problems more often than not. Dim blocks at the top should be avoided as well. It is always best to 'declare variables as close to when they are used as possible'. Additionally, your constant `SRCS_VAL` is a Variant.

Comment: Thanks for the observations @Brandon - you make good points but some of them are subjective, and so are some of my reasons. The use of `:` is not only visually pleasing but, in my opinion, it also aligns each case with its result, making it obvious without the eye having to search the next line(s). The discrepancy between GetSelectedLetter and GetSelection was caused by a hasty edit without testing it in the editor. I also disagree about the Exit Function statements: I am quite particular about performance, and if you'll step through the code you'll notice that it replaces two extra steps

Comment: I am not in favor of declaring each variable on its own line - given today's displays you'll end up with a large unused vertical portion of the editor, and I'd rather avoid scrolling vertically and horizontally if possible, and not be limited by the old-fashioned 80 character limit. I also got used to a certain discipline of grouping variables by usage, functionality, or sequence so this may not apply to everyone. However I do agree that variables should be declared as closed to their first use (scope) as possible and I'm working on changing the old habit

Comment: `Additionally, your constant SRCS_VAL is a Variant` - Wrong! Don't make this statement before knowing the facts. You can verify the type like this: `Debug.Print VarType(SRC_VAL) -> 8 (String)` or `Debug.Print TypeName(SRC_VAL) -> String`. I intentionally left out the constant type after I tested [this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2958/constants-const#t=201706282050159664135) in the VBA documentation

Comment: Actually, you are mistaken even still about SRCS_VAL. While it may contain a string, and it may be treated as a string, the compiler knows it as a Variant since it is never given a type. The compiler is unable to infer the type automatically, regardless of what the variable appears to be at runtime.

Comment: Regarding variable declaration, I strongly recommend looking up the SOLID principles of programming as as well as Bob Martin's videos, and articles about code smells and making bad code look bad. Once you do, you should understand why your variable declaration habits are poor habits to have. I understand the organizational side of things, but code should be well designed first and foremost, and should leave aesthetics to be a benefit of a good design.

Comment: Likewise, while the exit function command does exit two steps sooner (finalization of the conditional blocks) it is clunky and certainly will make a negligible impact (if any at all) on performance. The colon line continuation is a highly frowned upon habit for many reasons. Use it if you wish, but there is a reason why its a code smell. Additionally, some code parsers will be unable to process it successfuly.

Comment: Code Review is for improvement as a community. Don't get all fired up when someone who is trying to help points out the error in your ways. I can guarantee that programmers with more experience than you would point out those errors and provide the same recommendations (and I know this because I was doing those exact same things until experienced programmers taught me the error of my ways). Keep bad behaviors if you wish, but they are, without a doubt, bad behaviors.

Comment: Fist off, I didn't get fired up, I was just pointing out that your opinions are just that: YOUR opinions - you are entitled to them, just as much as I am entitled to mine. My first priority is to determine coding practices that helps me eliminate errors early, and later on simplify my maintenance work; if my practice deviates from the "bible" so be it (I'm flexible) and not forcing anyone to follow them, I just provide other options

Comment: Your statement: _SRCS_VAL. While it may contain a string, and it may be treated as a string, the compiler knows it as a Variant since it is never given a type. The compiler is unable to infer the type automatically, regardless of what the variable appears to be at runtime_ - can you back this up with any technical reference from Microsoft? (I'm willing to improve if you can show me the facts). Also I think you're still not make the proper distinction between declaration of variables and constants (SRCS_VAL is not a variable)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61286/discussion-between-brandon-barney-and-paul-bica).